# SQL Server 2008 create procedure and create view

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, view

I was trying to create a view and a procedure. However none of them can be done.

I have tried creating the procedure like this:

```
create procedure name ( @time )
as 
begin
    select tag_ID from Location where tag_ID=@time;
end

create procedure name 
as 
    select tag_ID from Location where tag_ID=@time;
end
```

Both result in the following error

> Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 25501
>   create procedure name 
>   as 
>   select tag_ID from Location where tag_ID=@time
>   There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = procedure ]

For creating view

```
create view Time as select time from Location;
```

The error I received is:

> Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 25501
>   create view Time as select time from Location
>   There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = view ]

It seems to be some problem in using the CREATE, however i cannot figure it out.

I have tried most of the syntax but it seems not working, most of them pop out the same error.

** I am using SQL compact edition.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the type from the procedure parameter.  Try something like this:

```
CREATE procedure name ( @time varchar(100)) 
AS BEGIN
    select tag_ID from Location where tag_ID=@time; 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Error Because You are missing `datatype for procedure's parameter`.
Note : Please recheck which datatype you are using I'm using datetime here.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Name (@time DATETIME)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT tag_id
  FROM   location
  WHERE  tag_id = @time;
END
```

Comment: The error still exists with the same error message, I have tried to create a procedure without any variable(i.e. create procedure as begin select tag_id from Location end )

Comment: @NadiiLo every version of the code you post has a different syntax error.  In the one above, you have an **end** keyword, but no **begin**.  Try using one of the answers posted here.

Comment: CREATE procedure name  
AS BEGIN
    select tag_ID from Location; 
END

and the error message:

Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 25501
> CREATE procedure name  
AS BEGIN
    select tag_ID from Location
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = procedure ]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Sql Server Database Engine or SQL CE? I think You are using SQL CE or Limited version in which View and Procedures are not allowed;

Ref
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/sqlce/thread/f6ba9114-a962-41c2-b142-448c0f427cce

Comment: Thanks. Though nothing can be done, it relieved my confusion. :)

Comment: @NadiiLo _Are_ you using CE? If so, you should update your question to tell potential answer writers that...